# Backup Windows 8.1 partition to new hard disk using Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning

I want to reinstall Windows 8.1 on my machine, but keep the current Windows installation running for a short period of time on another machine, e.g. to access Chrome passwords or missing files easily. Usually we've done that by purchasing a new (faster) SSD and installing on that one, but now I want to install on the same (already fast) SSD and have the backup on an old spare hard-disk.

Is it possible to backup the Windows NTFS partition(s) using Linux to another hard disk, so it remains bootable? If so, what are the required steps?

Comment: Look into getting Clonezille for the drive image backups. Use Gparted for the paritioning and formatting of the new drive. I've used both these Linux tools with great success with WIndows OSes doing what you are describing. I don't have the step-by-step detail so perhaps someone else can plug it in as an answer or else you can use this as starting point to research further.

Comment: Which version of 8.1 are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there are numerous free Linux imaging utilities, such as Clonezilla that @LMFAO_A_JOKE suggests, all must be run on an *unmounted* partition, AFAIK. You might prefer to image Windows using [Macrium Reflect free or an alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/), since they use Windows' Shadow Copy. You can also make a recovery disk using Linux or WinPE with these utilities.

Clonezilla and [alternative applications](http://alternativeto.net/software/clonezilla/?platform=linux) I've seen all require booting from other media (e.g. USB drive or CD) to image the primary disk. This is about the only are where I find Linux less convenient than Windows. BTW, if someone knows of a (free) Linux program that can do so, please comment here!